# zend framework 2 change head title

Tags: header, zend-framework2, title, page-title

I'm trying to change headtitle on ZF2 but it always say "ZF2 Skeleton Application" when i paste it on FB
How can I change it?
I tried few things and cant make it work

I event tried raw HTML inside head tag to put it and it doesn't work, BUT on my other pages this works but don't know why

```
echo $this->headTitle('you are on '.$news.' ');
```

inside PHP ofc

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set head title, Do not use 'echo' in front, just use:

```
$this->headTitle('you are on ...');
```

...in your view php file.

If you want to change the head title from inside a controller method use:

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('HeadTitle')->set('my title')
```

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding you want to change the head title of the main (front page).
You can put the following in your layout.phtml page.

```
<?php echo $this->headTitle('you are on'. $this->translate($news))->setSeparator(' - ')->setAutoEscape(false); ?>
```